# fix segmentation fault with vfprintf.c

Tags: c

I am making a simple GUI with a gnuplot window and for some reason I've started getting a segmentation fault error. I tried running gdb to find the problem. I added a modified function in [gnuplot_i](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/gnuplot_i/index.html) and everything seems to work fine until it seemingly randomly gives me the seg. fault error. this is what I get from gbd:

```
    Thread 4 "interface" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    [Switching to Thread 0x7fffdfb52700 (LWP 21382)]
    _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x0, format=0x555555557a14 "%f.18e %f.18e\n", 
        ap=ap@entry=0x7fffdfb51a10) at vfprintf.c:1278
    1278    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
    (gdb) backtrace
    #0  0x00007ffff6ccc640 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x0, format=0x555555557a14 "%f.18e %f.18e\n", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffdfb51a10) at vfprintf.c:1278
    #1  0x00007ffff6cd5c04 in __fprintf (stream=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>)
        at fprintf.c:32
    #2  0x0000555555556e7c in gnuplot_plot_xy_double (handle=0x5555558c5550, x=0x55555575a058 <buffs+4024>, y=0x5555557590b8 <buffs+24>, x1=0x55555575bf98 <buffs+12024>, y1=0x55555575aff8 <buffs+8024>, n=500, title=0x555555557859 "Channel 1", title2=0x55555555784f "Channel 2", line=0x555555557834 "linetype 1", line2=0x555555557844 "linetype 2")
        at src/gnuplot_i.c:470
    #3  0x00005555555563b1 in UpdateGraph () at src/main.c:165
    #4  0x0000555555555f2a in Backend (vargp=0x0) at src/main.c:82
    #5  0x00007ffff705fe64 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
    #6  0x00007ffff6d8b12f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

I ran this multiple times and everytime the error was on this line:

```
fprintf(tmpfd2,"%f.18e %f.18e\n", x1[i], y1[i]);
```

but I can't figure out why this line always causes a problem when in a previous line an almost identical code never caused an error. this is the function that I modified.

```
    void gnuplot_plot_xy_double(
        gnuplot_ctrl    *   handle,
        double          *   x,
        double          *   y,
        double          *   x1,
        double          *   y1,
        int                 n,
        char            *   title,
        char            *   title2,
        char            *   line,
        char            *   line2
    )
    {
        int     i ;
        FILE*   tmpfd ;
        char const * tmpfname;
        FILE*   tmpfd2 ;
        char const * tmpfname2;

        if (handle==NULL || x==NULL || y==NULL || x1==NULL || y1==NULL || (n<1)) return ;

        /* Open temporary file for output   */
        tmpfname = gnuplot_tmpfile(handle);
        tmpfd = fopen(tmpfname, "w");
        /* Open temporary file for output   */
        tmpfname2 = gnuplot_tmpfile(handle);
        tmpfd2 = fopen(tmpfname2, "w");

        if (tmpfd == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"cannot create temporary file: exiting plot") ;
            return ;
        }

        /* Write data to this file  */
        for (i=0 ; i<n; i++) {
            fprintf(tmpfd, "%f.18e %f.18e\n", x[i], y[i]);
        }
        fclose(tmpfd) ;
        for (i=0 ; i<n; i++) {
            fprintf(tmpfd2,"%f.18e %f.18e\n", x1[i], y1[i]);
        }
        fclose(tmpfd2) ;
        
        char const *    cmd    = (handle->nplots > 0) ? "replot" : "plot";
        title                  = (title == NULL)      ? "(none)" : title;
        gnuplot_cmd(handle, "%s \"%s\" title \"Channel 1\" with %s linetype 1, \"%s\" title \"Channel 2\" with %s linetype 2", 
                            cmd, tmpfname, handle->pstyle, tmpfname2, handle->pstyle) ;
        handle->nplots++ ;
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: Please post an  [MCVE]. `_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x0` - so, well, `tmpfd2` is NULL.

Comment: I assume that `gnuplot_tmpfile(handle)` returns the same value each time it is called.  If this is the case, then you are opening the same file twice and for write only in both cases.  You do test for `tmpfd == NULL`, but never test for `tmpfd2 == NULL`.  I suspect that you second call to `fopen` is failing.

Comment: What are you expecting `%f.18e` to do?  AFAIK it will just print something like `123.456789.18e`; is that really what you intend?  It seems like strange output to want.  It's unrelated to the crash but may be a separate issue.

Comment: @JonBelanger: No, it looks like `gnuplot_tmpfile` returns a new filename every time.  Its source is [here](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/gnuplot_i/gnuplot__i_8c_source.html#l00658).  But it does have a fixed maximum number of temp files that it will create, even if you close them, so if OP's function is called many times, that limit may be hit.  This would explain a NULL return.

Comment: Looking at the source code you provided for the `gnuplot_tmpfile`,there are a couple of possibilities.  If any error occurs, then NULL is returned.  Additionally, it also looks like you have a memory leak.  This function allocates a buffer in which to store the file name, but your code never frees is.  This function also has a bug.  If the buffer is allocated and a NULL is returned, the buffer is also never freed.

Comment: @JonBelanger: I thought about the first "memory leak" but since `gnuplot_tmpfile` retains a pointer to the file name in the `handle->tmp_filename_tbl` array, the caller must not free it.  It is used again, and then freed, when you call [`gnuplot_close`](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/gnuplot_i/gnuplot__i_8h.html#a416bd48453ce016d6419f0f39fa5c625).

Comment: Nate Eldredge, %f.18e is supposed to give me a float, it is just for saving it to a file for gnuplot. also I didnt realize that there is a limit to the number of files that can be created, I think I will edit the code somemore so I only create 2 files (one for each buffer)

Comment: @user169808: Then maybe you intended to write `%.18e` or `%.18f`?  But `%f.18e` just outputs a number in ordinary `%f` format and appends the literal characters `.18e`.

Comment: yes you are right, i switched to %.18f. what I find odd is that I only have two tempfiles at any one time, but I will try to just create 2 on boot and keep clearing it as I need to

Comment: @NateEldredge: removinggnuplot_tempfile and leaving a fixed name for each buffer seems to have solved the problem. now the code runs. thanks.
JonBelanger: seems like I was hitting the hard limit, thanks